# cygwin bash: java: command not found

Tags: java, cygwin

So I had to re-install my system.
I installed Cygwin in C:\cygwin\bin

And I used the batch file that worked on my previous installation:
"start_cygwin.bat"

```
@echo off  
C:  
chdir C:\cygwin\bin  
bash -c "cd /cygdrive/e/apache-solr-3.5.0/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar"
```

But after running this command:

```
bash -c "cd /cygdrive/e/apache-solr-3.5.0/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar"
```

I get the error:

*bash: java: command not found*

I thought it had something to do with java, but I installed the java jdk 6.27 (which worked fine before) and when I type "java" in my command prompt I see a list of possible java commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not able to locate your `java.exe` file.

To resolve the issue, you have two options:

1. Add Java installed folder in your PATH
2. Use full path of `java.exe` in the above command  i.e. in place of `java`, use `/home/../jdk.../bin/java`.

One of the tow options, should help resolving your issue.

Comment: +1 it could be in your CMD's path but not for bash. Try running java under bash and see what you get. If that doesn't work, use the full path to java instead.

Comment: On my system (Cygwin under Windows 7), `type java` says `java is /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java`; it's a Windows installation, not part of Cygwin. I have `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32` in my Cygwin `$PATH`. Note that Cygwin's `$PATH` is (at least partly) independent of the Windows `%PATH%`.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work using the path to java/bin then you can try to 
 - create symbolic link: `ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe /usr/bin/java` 
 - create an alias: `alias java="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java.exe"` 
 - add the java path to the paths: `export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102"` 
`export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`